# Can only Putty into EC2 spot machine one time

Tags: ssh, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

I'm creating AWS EC2 spot machine instances in the AWS console based on ami-062f7200baf2fa504 (Linux 64-bit, amzn2-ami-hvm-2.0.20191217.0-x86_64_gp2). I can SSH into the instances once without problems using Putty (hostname: ec2-user), but if I close the instance window and try to Putty in again, I either get an "Server unexpectedly closed network connection" error or "Network error: Software caused connection abort." So, I can only Putty into these machines one time.

I'm using a launch template to create my spot instances. I can successfully SSH into spot requests based on another AMI multiple times using the same launch template with the same configuration aside from the AMI (like VPC, subnet, instance type) and using the same settings in Putty (except changing the hostname to reflect the other AMI, which is a custom one a colleague built).

Any ideas about why I can't SSH into spot requests based on ami-062f7200baf2fa504 multiple times and how to fix that? Thanks.

Comment: What region is the AMI in?

Comment: When I create the request in the template (regardless of which AMI I use), I select us-east options 1a through 1f. I guess that based on availability, the request gets assigned to one of those regions, so the actual region of the instance changes from instance to instance. But this is the case for the AMI I can't Putty into multiple times and the AMI that I can.

Comment: I did the same: created `t3.small` *spot* instance in `us-east-1` from the same AMI as you did, and I can login as many times as I want. Not quite sure why you're observing these issues. You can use **Session Manager** to get access to the instance when SSH fails and investigate what's going on: https://aws.nz/best-practice/ssm-session-manager/